# How would I make a number loop back to the start when adding to it?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

What I am  trying to do is add a number to each value in the array, but if the value is greater than 78 but less than 90, I want it to loop back around to 65 once it passes the number 90. Meaning, if I added 10 onto 85, it would give me 70.

Here is what I have to far. I just can't figure out what to  put after the if statement.

```
emptyArr = [83, 69, 82, 82] 

function addingNum(x) {
 for(var k=0 ;  k < emptyArr.length ; k++){
  if (emptyArr[k] >= 78 && emptyArr[k] <= 90  ){



  }
  else {
      emptyArr[k] += 13;   
    }
}

 return emptyArr;
}
```

Comment: Your question is confusing.  You use `10` as an example and your code has `13`.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

just add this inside if:

```
emptyArr[k] += 10;
if(emptyArr[k] >= 90) emptyArr[k] = 65 + emptyArr[k] - 90;
```

Comment: thank you, that worked. I realized I still have to add the value of 12 to it to get to the number I need. But your solution worked. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
emptyArr[k] = 65 + ((emptyArr[k] + x) % 90)
```

Being `x` the number you want to add.

Demo:

```js
emptyArr = [85, 83, 69, 82, 82, 90, 91]

function addingNum(x) {
  for (var k = 0; k < emptyArr.length; k++) {
    if (emptyArr[k] >= 78 && emptyArr[k] <= 90) {

      emptyArr[k] = 65 + ((emptyArr[k] + x) % 90)

    } else {
      emptyArr[k] += x;
    }
  }
  return emptyArr;
}

console.log(addingNum(10));
```

---

If you want to keep it between 65 and 90 no matter what `x` (the value added), also use `%` in `x`, like:

```
emptyArr[k] = 65 + ((emptyArr[k] + (x % 25)) % 90)
```

Demo:

```js
emptyArr = [85, 83, 69, 82, 82, 90, 91]

function addingNum(x) {
  for (var k = 0; k < emptyArr.length; k++) {
    if (emptyArr[k] >= 78 && emptyArr[k] <= 90) {

      emptyArr[k] = 65 + ((emptyArr[k] + (x % 25)) % 90)

    } else {
      emptyArr[k] += x;
    }
  }
  return emptyArr;
}

console.log(addingNum(35));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the difference to the lower bound:

```js
let arr = [83, 69, 82, 82]
console.log(addingNum([...arr], 10))

function addingNum(arr, x) {
  let maxNum = 90,
    minNum = 78
    
  for (var k = 0, n = arr.length; k < n; k++) {
    if (arr[k] >= minNum && arr[k] <= maxNum) {
      let newNum = arr[k] + x
      let difference = newNum - maxNum
      if (difference > 0)
        arr[k] = minNum + difference
    } else {
      arr[k] += 13
    }
  }

  return arr
}
```